# Method to find out how distributed are a certain set of data?

Tags: geometry, uniform-distribution

Assume I have array of $A_{3\times120}$

Each row of matrix A corresponds to a shape which is generated by its three row elements as below:

$r=1+a_1\cos(\theta)+a_2\cos(2\theta)+a_3\cos(3\theta)$ where $\theta$ varies from 0 to $2\pi$

Where

$x=r\cos(\theta)$; $y=r\sin(\theta)$

Assuming all shapes will have same area, what kind of combinations of $a_i$ do you suggest that I take to see how distributed my shapes are?

Maybe one would say sort them based on $1\times a_1^3+ 2\times a_2^3 +3\times a_3^3$

What way do you suggest?

Sort the shapes based on what to have a stencil implying how different is one shape from the other?

Comment: I understand that r is given and $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$, am I right?
Also, what do you mean by distribution of shapes?

Comment: @pajonk for instance two shapes of [a1,a2,a3]=[0.1,0.1,0.12] and [0.1,0.1,0.11] are more similar than shapes of [a1,a2,a3]=[0.1,0.1,0.12] and [0.11,0.1,0.1] . But what parameterization could capture this extent of difference and could be used as a comparison of difference in shapes without drawing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ideas:

1. (more "graphical") calculate the values of these curves on a grid, eg. let $x$ be from $-k$ to $k$ with some step $h=\frac{k}{n}$. Then calculate $y$ values for this set of $x$ coordinates and check in which interval it belongs. To compare two shapes: count matching "pixels".
2. You can use some measure of difference ([metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))) between functions (your shapes are in fact functions), eg. $\int_0^{2\pi}|f-g|$ or $\sup\limits_{(0,2\pi)}|f-g|$.
3. Apart from comparing values in some points (no.1.), you can also compare derivatives in a way described in 1. or in 2.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to do 1st one, but for the second and third they are not good measures since, you consider only an oval shape that initially is vertical (state1) then it is rotated 45 degree (state 2) then again rotated 45 degree (now a horizontal oval state 3) the 2nd measure should give same values for each two of them since it only takes into account the area between their profile. However, state 1 is very different than state 3